# search from the first letter of first name or last name in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to search first name or last name from the beginning of characters. For example, firstname is Michael and lastname is Jordan. 
If I search "dan" or "hae" words, it shouldn't return result.  Only if I search "mic" or "jor", it should return firstname and lastname together.
Is there any way to do it with mysql ?

My following code does not return what I expect.

```
select * from users where (firstname like '%$searchWord%' or lastname like '%$searchWord%')
```

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Absolutely not necessary in this situation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to search from the beginning of the word you have to place your wildcards only at the end of the condition:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`firstname` LIKE '$searchWord%' OR `lastname` LIKE '$searchWord%')
```

Comment: And if it is important for firstname to start `mic` AND lastname to start `jor` you might want to change OR to AND. But only if that is important

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first % in your query for each term.

```
select * from users where (firstname like '$searchWord%' or lastname like '$searchWord%')
```

This will search for the first letters exactly with anything that matches following.